# How to add persian Fonts to Next.js?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, persian, next.js

I can't add Persian Fonts to my Next.js in ubuntu and my fonts url is :static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.eot . I used dangerouslySetInnerHTML but still not working in ubuntu.I dont understand why works in mac os

[font URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsAlW.png) 
-I tried this in my code:

```
return (
  <html lang="en" dir="rtl"> 
    <Head>
      <title>فراخوان نقد</title>
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      {/* Use minimum-scale=1 to enable GPU rasterization */}
      <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
      />
      {/* PWA primary color */}
      <meta name="theme-color" content={pageContext.theme.palette.primary.main} />
      {/* <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
        family=Roboto:300,400,500"
      /> */}
       <link 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0- 
        alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      />
      <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
        @font-face {
          font-family:
          'IranSans,tahoma';
          font-style:
          normal;
          font-weight:
          400;
          src:
          url("../static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.eot");
          src:
            url("../static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.eot?#iefix") 
             format('embedded-opentype'),
              url("../static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff2") 
              format('woff2'),
              url("../static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff") 
              format('woff'),
              url("../static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.ttf") 
              format('truetype');
        }
        body{
          font-family:
        'IranSans, tahoma' !important
        }
        `}}/>
    </Head>
    <body>
      <Main />
      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </html>
);
```

Comment: I tried @font-face and worked in mac os but still doesn't work in ubuntu.

Comment: Hello, can you edit your question to show what you tried plz ?

Comment: @Clément Prévost  yes of course.

Comment: where did you put this code ? what is rendered in the html ?

Comment: Also, where is your `Fonts` folder?

Answer (score 1):

One solution requiring **ontfaceobserver**. 
change fonts according to your choice

**Fonts.js**

```
const FontFaceObserver = require('fontfaceobserver')

const Fonts = () => {
  const link = document.createElement('link')
  link.href = 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900'
  link.rel = 'stylesheet'

  document.head.appendChild(link)

  const roboto = new FontFaceObserver('Roboto')

  roboto.load().then(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.add('roboto')
  })
}

export default Fonts
```

**Then on my index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Home from '@/Home'
import Fonts from '~/general/Fonts'

class Index extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    Fonts()
  }

  render () {
    return <Home />
  }
}

export default Index
```

Comment: thanks but I should use website font( this font has used and can not be changed)

Comment: If you are copying the response from somewhere else you should reference it:
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/512#issuecomment-322026199

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple things that I can see that might be root of the issue

1) [Static folder](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#static-file-serving-eg-images) is referenced as absolute path `/static/file.txt` inside the next.js app

2) Instead of using `style dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you can use [style jsx](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#built-in-css-support) that is built in by default in next.js

So the resulted code should look like this

```
<Head>
  <style global jsx>{`
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'CustomIranSans';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: url("/static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.eot");
      src: url("/static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("/static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("/static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff") format('woff'),
        url("/static/Fonts/IRANSansWeb.ttf") format('truetype');
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'CustomIranSans', Tahoma;
    }
  `}</style>
</Head>
```

Hope this helps!